# weird iptables log messages after upgraded to server zesty-17.04

Tags: server, iptables, firewall, log, virtualbox-networking

I'm almost sure I didn't have these messages before the upgrade. Can anyone direct me to the reason of them? I've found some links at Google related to devs bugs but I'm not sure if there's something I need to worry about:

```
kernel: [43101.907635] nf_conntrack: default automatic helper assignment has been turned off for security reasons and CT-based  firewall rule not found. Use the iptables CT target to attach helpers instead.
```

This log comes from a firewall machine running as gateway to internet with iptables filtering traffic to/from extenrnal (pppoe) interface, for the case it has something to do.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the messages is the change for kernel 4.7

[automatic-helper-assignment](http://www.firewalld.org/2016/10/automatic-helper-assignment)

> With kernel 4.7 and up the automatic helper assignment in kernel has
>   been turned off by default. Netfilter conntrack helpers like for
>   example nf_conntrack_ftp now need to be used in a different way. See
>   Secure use of iptables and connection tracking helpers for more
>   information.
>
> The new AutomaticHelpers configuration setting has been added to
>   firewalld.conf:
>
> AutomaticHelpers
>   For the secure use of iptables and connection tracking helpers it is
>   recommended to turn AutomaticHelpers off. But this might have side effects on
>   other services using the netfilter helpers as the sysctl setting in
>   /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_helper will be changed.
>   With the system setting, the default value set in the kernel or with sysctl
>   will be used. Possible values are: yes, no and system.
>   Default: system AutomaticHelpers=system
>
> firewalld is now checking the
>   /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_helper kernel setting at start.
>   With AutomaticHelpers set to system, this is the default, firewalld
>   will use the actual setting in the kernel. This could wither be the
>   default in the kernel itself or has been set using sysctl.
>
> If automatic helper assignment is turned off, firewalld will create
>   rules in the PREROUTING chain of the raw table to enable the helper
>   for the zone, where it is used. For this it uses the helper settings
>   defined in the new helpers. These are the nf_conntrack_ module that
>   provides the helper, the optional family if a helper could only be
>   used for IPv4 or IPv6 and also the ports. The helper will only listen
>   on the ports defined in the helper configuration. If there is a need
>   to modify these ports, then it is possible to create an adapted
>   configruaiton either with the GUI or command line tools or by copying
>   the file to /etc/firewalld/helpers. If you want to change the
>   protocol, please make sure that the helper is able to use this
>   protocol. There is only a limited amount of helpers that are abel to
>   handle more than one protocol.
>
> Here is an example of the ftp helper added by enabling the ftp service
>   in the public zone:
>
> ```
> # iptables -t raw -S | grep CT
> -A PRE_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j CT --helper ftp
> ```
>
> A new backend has been added, the D-Bus interface has been extended,
>   also the GUI and command line tools and the documentation.

For more info see [[Solved] nf_conntrack default automatic helper assignment](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=224647)

Comment: Hi Yaron, thanks for your answer. Firstly I saw that now every "-m state --state" statements should be replaced by the new form "-m conntrack --ctstate". I reviewd my iptables rules and saw that in fact I had a few of them with that syntax. Anyways, also noticed that now "For each helper, you must carefully open the RELATED flow. All iptables statements using “-m conntrack –ctstate RELATED” should be used in conjunction with the choice of a helper and of IP parameters <..>" so need to review this in detail.

Comment: thanks Yaron, I though I had already do so...